# If $X\subset Y$ then $X^*\subset Y^*$

Tags: banach-spaces, duality-theorems

Is the following true,

If $X$ and $Y$ are Banach spaces and $X\subset Y$, then $X^*\subset Y^*$.

One argument for this is the following let $i:X\to Y$ be the identity map which implies its one to one and hence $i^* : Y^*\to X^*$ is onto which implies $X^* \subset Y^*$.
 Thank you

Comment: If $X$ is a (closed) subspace of $Y$, then $i^\ast$ is surjective, hence $X^\ast$ is a quotient of $Y^\ast$ (up to canonical identifications, $X^\ast \cong Y^\ast/X^\perp$, where $X^\perp$ is the annihilator of $X$ in $Y^\ast$), but in general, you don't have a natural embedding of $X^\ast$ into $Y^\ast$. You have one if $X$ is a complemented subspace. If you only have a continuous injection of $X$ into $Y$ (that includes the case where $X$ is a subset of $Y$, but the topology considered on $X$ is strictly finer than the subspace topology), things are different.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the reverse statement is (more or less) true.

I assume that by $X \subset Y$, you mean that the inclusion

$$
\iota : X \to Y, x \mapsto x
$$

is a well-defined, bounded linear map.

Then, for each $\varphi \in Y^\ast$, we get that $\varphi|_X = \varphi \circ \iota \in X^{\ast}$.

If also $X \subset Y$ is dense, then the "inclusion" map

$$
\Gamma : Y^\ast \to X^\ast , \varphi \mapsto \varphi|_X
$$

is also **injective** (why?), so that we can consider $Y^\ast$ as a subspace of $X^\ast$, using $\Gamma$ as the identification.

Your inclusion does not hold in general. To see this, consider the inclusion $X := C^1([a,b]) \subset C^0 ([a,b]) =: Y$, where we equip these spaces with the usual norms. Then

$$
\varphi : C^1([a,b]) \to \Bbb{C}, f \mapsto f'((a+b)/2)
$$

is a bounded linear functional on $C^1$, but it is easy to see that it has no continuous extension to $C^0$, because $\varphi$ is **not** bounded w.r.t. the $C^0$-norm (why?).

Hence, $\varphi \in X^\ast$, but $\varphi \notin Y^\ast$ (in any reasonable sense), so that $X^\ast \subset Y^\ast$ does **not** hold.

Comment: BTW: Why do/did you think that $i^\ast$ is onto?

Comment: If the inclusion is a true inclusion, i.e. $X$ is a (closed) subspace of $Y$, then Hahn-Banach says the restriction $i^\ast$ is surjective. The OP may mean that, or may not know exactly that and how the difference between an inclusion and a continuous injection matters.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Oh, ok, so if the OP meant that $X$ is a subspace of $Y$ (equipped with the **same** norm, restricted to $X$), then $i^\ast$ is surjective. Thanks for the clarification.